# Plotly: How to create 'input text' on one page and output (graphs) on second page or tab, by using plotly-dash?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

I am creating an app where the first page should take only 'text input' and results(graph) must show on second page or new tab. I do not want text input and charts on the same page. It means, if I write the input as 'USA' in text input bar, the graph of USA should populate on second tab. Following is the working code that I have written so far in dropdown format. In this code, dropdown and graphs are on the same page which I do not want. Please suggest.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
import numpy as np
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default='browser'


          
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("Economy Analysis"),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='Country_select',
                 options=[{'label': x, 'value': x}
                 for x in df.Country.unique()],
    value = 'USA'
    ),
    dcc.Graph(id ='my-graph', figure = {})
    ])

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id = 'my-graph', component_property = 'figure'),
    Input(component_id = 'Country_select', component_property = 'value'))

def interactive_graphing(value_country):
    print(value_country)
    s = 100
    cat_g = ["developing","develop"]
    sample_cat = [cat_g[np.random.randint(0,2)]for i in range(100)]
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Country": np.random.choice(["USA", "JPY", "MEX", "IND", "AUS"], s),                   
              "Net": np.random.randint(5, 75, s),
        })
   df["sample_cat"] = sample_cat
   df = df[df.Country==value_country]
   df2 = df.pivot_table(index='Country',columns='sample_cat',values='Net',aggfunc='sum')
   df2.reset_index(inplace=True)

   fig = px.bar(df2, x="Country",
          y=['develop','developing'])

   return fig


if __name__=='__main__':
   app.run_server()
```

Comment: https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/tabs is this what you are looking for?

Comment: No. My first web page should contain only 'text input bar' and once I select the value, the results should open in new browser.

Comment: Just saw these comments. Dash will not open any links in a new browser tab or page to my knowledge. You may need to explore Flask for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dcc.Tabs` and `dcc.Tab` containers in your layout, and put the input/graph in separate tabs. Dash bootstrap components tabs would also work for this. The ids will still work as inputs/outputs with your callback.

Sample layout:

```py
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("Economy Analysis"),
    
    dcc.Tabs([
        dcc.Tab(
            label='Dropdown',
            children=[
                dcc.Dropdown(id='Country_select',
                             options=[{'label': x, 'value': x}
                             for x in df.Country.unique()],
                             value = 'USA')
            ]
        ),
        dcc.Tab(
            label='Graph',
            children=[
                dcc.Graph(id ='my-graph')
            ]
        )
    ])
])
```